# Typedefs inside a class

Tags: c++, class, typedef

Let's say I have a class with an expensive constructor, and let's say I don't need to create the constructor because it's "simple". Inside the class, I want to put a typedef. All together, it looks like:

```
class Expensive {
public:
    typedef double data_type;
    data_type data[100000][100000];
};
```

Now, in my calling code, if I do:

```
Expensive::data_type singleValue;
```

is that going to create a temporary instance of `Expensive` and allocate all that space for the data just to get access to the typedef?

Comment: Good luck allocating that on a stack. BTW why don't you write `data_type data[100000][100000];`?

Comment: It was a contrived example to highlight the question; if I was using the Intel compiler and really wanted that to work, there's a flag to put all arrays on the heap anyway. Or `ulimit` my stack to unlimited.

Comment: Alright but it's a bit of a silly example since (a) it's poor code, and (b) it won't work in most configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: No. The operation has no runtime effect whatsoever. Even just declaring a double is not guaranteed to have any effect at runtime as along as you are not using it ;)

Answer (score 0):

No; you are accessing what is effectively a static member of the class. No instance is created, and thus no huge huge array.